# How can I use an access token for accesing Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) from inside Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I'm trying to use the Git client inside Visual Studio Code. I have my Git repository on Team Services.
In the Team Services site, I've created a "personal access token". When I try to pull from inside my Visual Studio Code I get the following screen.

[image]

Can I use my access token in this dialog? I've tried different usernames, but authentication always fails.

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://roadtoalm.com/2015/07/22/using-personal-access-tokens-to-access-visual-studio-online/) describe in details how to do it.

#### From the above article:

[image]

> When you create the token, you see a token (only visible after creation !) that you should copy and keep safe.

[image]

> This token alone is sufficient to authenticate against VSO. So when you now clone a Git repository you only have to fill in this token in the password box. Username can be empty or any value

[image]

The great thing is that you can revoke rights or the token afterwards and make sure that people cannot access stuff anymore

Comment: Thank you. I've seen this article, but unfortunaley this does not work for me. It works when using the commandprompt but not in the shown dialog.

Comment: You can switch you r URL to git/ssh and this way you will not need any password or token

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows). With this tool installed, you will get a "Sign in" dialog for [Visual Studio Online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server#On-premises_vs._online) when you pull from Visual Studio Code. You can simply enter your Visual Studio credentials in the dialog to sign in and the tool will manage the Git credentials automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This topic or links from this topic might help: [Use Git Credential Managers to Authenticate to Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/set-up-credential-managers)

It looks like there's also an [Visual Studio Team Services extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemname=ms-vsts.team) now that handles credential storage.